# Label Resolution in Plot3D with MaTeX

Tags: plotting, labeling

I am using `MaTeX` (check [this](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html) for installation) for labeling which works fine with `Plot` but with `Plot3D` the label resolution becomes very bad. How can I solve that?
For example, I have this code

```
fig = Plot3D[{Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], -Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 
   2}, PlotRange -> {-2.5, 2.5}, ClippingStyle -> None, 
  PlotPoints -> 80, Mesh -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
  PlotTheme -> "Grid", BoxRatios -> {0.5, 0.5, 0.9}, ImageSize -> 120,
   AxesLabel -> (MaTeX[#, Magnification -> 1] &) /@ {"lx", "ly", 
     "E(\\gamma)"}, AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Thin], 
  LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman", Black, 
    FontSize -> 9}, ViewPoint -> {1, -1, 0.6}]
```

[image]

Now, I export this as pdf using `Export["..../test1.pdf", fig, ImageResolution -> 2000]`. When I enlarge this one the labels are not smoothed (see labels) and resolution is bad (see ticks) as indicated by the red arrows in the below picture (I set `ImageResolution -> 2000` to obtain this quality)
[image]

**Update**
One can also impose the ticks using `MaTeX`

```
Plot3D[{Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], -Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 PlotRange -> {-2.5, 2.5}, ClippingStyle -> None, PlotPoints -> 80, 
 Mesh -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None, PlotTheme -> "Grid", 
 BoxRatios -> {0.5, 0.5, 0.9}, ImageSize -> 120, 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Thin], 
 BoxStyle -> Directive[Black, Thin], 
 AxesLabel -> {MaTeX["lx", Magnification -> 1], 
   MaTeX["ly", Magnification -> 1], 
   Rotate[MaTeX["\\text{E}(\\gamma)", Magnification -> 1], 
    90 Degree]}, AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.01]], 
 BoxStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.01]], 
 Ticks -> {With[{ticks = 
      Range[-2, 2, 2]}, {#, 
       MaTeX[NumberForm[#, {\[Infinity], 1}], "DisplayStyle" -> False,
         Magnification -> 1]} & /@ ticks], 
   With[{ticks = 
      Range[-2, 2, 2]}, {#, 
       MaTeX[NumberForm[#, {\[Infinity], 1}], "DisplayStyle" -> False,
         Magnification -> 1]} & /@ ticks], 
   With[{ticks = 
      Range[-2, 2, 2]}, {#, 
       MaTeX[NumberForm[#, {\[Infinity], 1}], "DisplayStyle" -> False,
         Magnification -> 1]} & /@ ticks]}, ViewPoint -> {1, -1, 0.6}]
```

and then export the results using the above statement which gives this
[image]

which shows that the problem exists even with the ticks when created by `MaTeX`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. What version of Mathematica did you use?

Comment: Note that the tick labels are not produced by MaTeX. The jaggedness looks like a misrendering of FilledCurve / BezierCurve in a 3D environment. I assume you don't see the jaggedness unless using Graphics3D? It looks like a Mathematica bug ... it should be reported to Wolfram.

Comment: What version is this?

Comment: @Szabolcs, I am using Mathematica 12.0.0.0 on Ubuntu. I updated the code to impose the ticks with MaTeX.

Comment: Please do keep the original version too, where ticks are not created with MaTeX. It seems to me that that shows an unrelated, but equally annoying issue.

Comment: @Szabolcs, I did not change the original post where tick are not created by MaTeX and intend to keep it like that. In the update, I showed that the problem presents with ticks too not only labels.

Comment: It probably has to do with BezierCurve in Graphics3D rather than whether these objects are in labels or elsewhere. Does this work correctly? `Graphics3D[{}, Boxed -> True, 
 Epilog -> {EdgeForm@Directive[Thick, Red], 
   FilledCurve@
    BezierCurve[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {1/2, -1/2}}, SplineClosed -> True]}]`

Comment: @Szabolcs, I do not understand how should I replace `Plot3D` with `Graphics3D`?!

Comment: No, `Plot3D` already outputs a `Graphics3D`. I am trying to help you construct a minimal example. Did you try the example from my comment above? Is the curve smooth or jagged?

Comment: @Szabolcs, at the top of the curve it is jagged. By the way, can't you still produce the problem? which Mathematica version do you use if ti works fine?

Comment: Works fine in 12.0.0 and 12.1.1 on macOS.

Comment: Have you contacted Wolfram about this bug? The minimal example I showed should make it easier to report it.

Comment: @Szabolcs, no I did not, where should I report this to Wolfram?. By the way, if I export it as .png not pdf it is smooth, any idea why is that?

Comment: https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=Feedback